# Different answer using fast I/O C++

Tags: c++, printf, c++14, sieve

So I have been trying to write the program for generating 1st, 101st, 201st prime till 10^8. I used ios_base and the output changed because of that,

```
vector<int> primes;
int maxx = 100000000;
int arr[100000000];

void sieve(){
  arr[0] = 1;
  arr[1] = 1;
  arr[2] = 0;
  primes.push_back(2);
  for(int i = 3;i < maxx; i+=2){
      if(arr[i]==0){
          primes.push_back(i);
          if(i*(ll)i < (ll)maxx){
              for(int j = i*i; j < maxx; j+=2*i){
                  arr[j] = 1;
              }
          }
      }
  }
}

int main()
{
    sieve();
    int i = 0, s= primes.size();
    while(i < s) {
        printf("%d\n", prime[i]);
        i += 100;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This gives the proper answer and the solution is accepted, however if I add

```
ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
cin.tie(NULL);
```

not many lines are generated and the answer is wrong.
Why does that happen? I searched everywhere but people only say it makes the program faster and thats it.

Comment: Please provide the incorrect output.

Comment: Why are you mixing `printf` with `<iostream>` operations?  Choose one or the other, not both.  Also, what is `ll`?  Is it one of those nutty macros copied from a "competitive programming" website?  If so, there is no need for this obfuscation in C++, as `int64_t` can now be used.

Comment: This is `for(int j = i*i; j < maxx; j+=2*i)` is wrong too, `i*i` can easily overflow the limit of `int`.

Comment: I do not understand the purpose of mixing raw arrays and STL containers, you can use vector everywhere you used c style array. For example you could write `vector<int> arr(100000000, 0)`.

Comment: @foragerDev If the array is global, then the stack is not involved, plus the array would be initialized to 0 automatically.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thanks, I did not know that before.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Oh I'll keep that in mind since most of the code I have seen in problems always involves macros. I'll use int64_t from here on.

Comment: @foragerDev Oh. That might be the problem than. I will keep that in mind, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

"ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
cin.tie(NULL);" makes the output faster only when there are multiple testcases.
And also here you are not taking any inputs I guess. So using cin.tie(NULL) might not be the best idea.

Comment: Your answer does not seem to be addressing the problem. His question is why his answer is wrong when he uses these lines of code?